# Grab Favicons from websites

Tags: html

I am trying to get Facebooks new circle favicon using https://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=facebook.com but it is giving me the old square one. How can I get the new one. Thanks

Comment: Like [this](https://www.iconfinder.com/icons/107175/circle_facebook_icon)?

Answer (score 0):

Why not try setting the image's border-radius to 50%?

Comment: I tried that but the f in the square logo is not centered. Thanks

Comment: Try using this https://static.xx.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/yD/r/d4ZIVX-5C-b.ico?_nc_eui2=AeG_8wIGaZwx_b7ab3U6HThCaBWfmC2eGbdoFZ-YLZ4ZtzWXZ9p4rdj5LerzWaODyrMo2TkhRyAIzL4PFJkcS-vd